# C# how convert hh:mm from excel cells

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.8

my value in excel cell has total time  : 227:20  and this format [hh]:mm

but not convert in c# this format and show 11:20 in gridview

my code:

```
model.ezafekari = DateTime.FromOADate((double)ws.Cells[rowNum, 17].Value).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: does `(double)ws.Cells[rowNum, 17].Value` = 256:02?

Comment: And what success result do you expect?

Comment: Work backwards within Excel.  Format a cell in Excel using `[hh]:mm`.  Enter `227:20` into the cell.  Now, copy that cell into another cell and format it as a date/time.  It shows up as `1/9/1900  11:20:00 AM`, i.e., 9 days, 11 hours and 20 minutes after the Excel epoch time. Paste that same value into another cell and format it general - you should see `9.47222222222222`.  Now divide 227 by 24, you should see 9 with a remainder of 11.  At this point, you should be able to figure out a formula

Comment: 227:20 show from excel

Comment: The HH format will show a value between 00 and 23. You will need your own formatting routine to show 227

Comment: Given the numeric value of the cell (`9.4722` in this case, put it in a cell named `real`), and using Excel formulas.for three values, Create 5 cells, name them days, `fracDays` `fracHours`, `hours` and `minutes`.  Then set the formulas in the cells to `days`: `TRUNC(real)`, `fracDays`: `real-TRUNC(real)`, fracHours`: `fracDays*24`, `hours`: TRUNC(fracHours)` and `minutes`: `(fracHours - hours) * 60`.  That results in 9 days, 11 hours and 20 minutes.  Not that `9*24 + 11` == `227`.  So, read the value of the cell in C# and translate all those formulas to C# and then format your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your formula:

```
(double)ws.Cells[rowNum, 17].Value
```

Will yield what Excel will show as the `General` formatted value for the cell (in my experience, that's what you see for date/time cells).  I'm not going to get code running against Excel.

Once you have that value, this should work:

```
var real = 9.472222222;         // should be (double)ws.Cells[rowNum, 17].Value
var days = (int)Math.Truncate(real);
var fracDays = real - days;
var fracHours = fracDays * 24.0;
var hours = (int) Math.Truncate(fracHours);
var minutes = (int) Math.Round ((fracHours - hours) * 60);
var totalHours = (days * 24) + hours;

var toShow = $"{totalHours}:{minutes}";
```

If you step through that code, you will see:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| days | 9 |
| hours | 11 |
| minutes | 20 |
| totalHours | 227 |
| toShow | 227:20 |